# Recommendations for Kegerator conversion kit?

Tags: serving

I have a mini fridge and looking to convert it into a kegerator with a tower tap on top. I've researched a few kegerator conversion kits and see economy, standard, deluxe, etc, kits available.

I'm not looking for a super fancy setup but a solid kegerator that will look good in my garage. Any recommendations for what conversion kit or how to best practices to convert a mini fridge to a kegerator?

Comment: Sorry to close this. Although we're not entirely strict (yet) about questions meeting SE standards, this question was both too broad (requesting product recommendations, best practices) and too opinion-based ("not super fancy", "look good"). I hope you'll participate in the site again nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

If you don't tap a beer every so often, the beer that is left in regular beer faucets can dry out and lock the tap shut.  I suggest a [perlick](https://www.perlick.com/bar-beverage-equipment/beverage-dispensing/tapping-hardwarecomponents/beer-faucets/) faucet as it seals without drying out.  I've used mine for years without any "sticky tap" problems.

If you are going to have a tower on top of the fridge, the beer line in the tower will warm up to the ambient room temperature.  This means that the first part of the first pour of the night will be very foamy as the pressure is different in the warm tower.  Some way of insulating the tower or circulating the air inside the tower will ensure the quality of the beer in the line.

When cutting the top of the fridge, be very careful to avoid damaging the cooling lines (if there are any in the top) as that will destroy the cooling ability on that wall of the refrigerator.

If you're keeping it in the garage, you may want to consider some way of sealing the tap when you're done for the night.  A plug will prevent flies or ants from enjoying your beer while you're out.  A lock will prevent any neighbors from doing the same.

Probably not as direct as a link to a conversion kit, but hopefully this will help you decide.

Comment: I wouldn't have even thought about insulating the tower or sealing the tap when done for the night. Thanks for the insights. This will help when researching/deciding on my final setup.